# Iincomplete validation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

There is a model:

```
public class Model
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(6), MinLength(6)]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(3)]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int? User { get; set; }
    }
```

If I pass null data in the User, Color, and Text fields, then the answer is:

```
{
    "code": "VALIDATION",
    "fields": [
        {
            "field": "user",
            "error": "REQUIRED"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why I do not get a complete list of required fields?

Comment: because you have some custom validation filter/middleware or some logic in action that returns the response

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, no, I have not

Comment: yes, you have. who is set VALIDATION to code? It is not default asp.net response model for validation. show us startup.cs and action from controller